# What is the proper way to make a UL change its parents size?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a unordered list of items to change its parents size.

I have something like this

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="product-range">
        <ul>
            <div class="product-container">sup</div>
            <div class="product-container">sup</div>
            <div class="product-container">sup</div>
            <div class="product-container">sup</div>
            <div class="product-container">sup</div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
    position:relative;
    background:white;
    max-width:1299px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
}
#product-range {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-right:15px;
    background:blue;
}
.product-container {
    position:relative;
    width:398px;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top:15px;
    background:green;
}
```

Which results in
http://jsfiddle.net/qfUTq/

The parent collapses into nothing. The only way I've been able to get around this is to add an empty div with a `clear:both` like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/eE6XQ/

Is there a proper way to go about doing this? I've tried to add that same property to all the other classes or ID and it doesn't produce the same effect.

Comment: yes, [clearing the floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) is the proper way. If you don't want to add another element, put that property on [`ul:after`](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html)

Comment: Does your [ul](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/ul) have an [li](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/li)?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev No, there isn't.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Just how necessary are they? Adding them has not fixed solved the problem. Playing with Overflow has though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On #product-range
play with overflow property :auto,scroll,...;

i guess overflow:auto cant solve your problem but its not the best way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Apply overflow: hidden to #product-range and it will wrap around the elements.